# Pilha de caracteres

Tags: c, char, stack

Boa Noite galera, tudo bem? To com meu programa aqui de Calculadora RPN e aparentemente tá tudo funcionando normal apesar de grandes dificuldades para se trabalhar com pilha de char.Está faltando implementar a função de potenciação na minha calculadora apenas,mas nada funciona, e meu resultado sempre sai como 0. Alguma ideia? Lembrando que as entradas do problema são N, que é qtd de caracteres da operação e outros N caracteres da conta logo abaixo. Um exemplo de entrada é :
`N = 7;E10E2-C` (10-2) . O 'E' empilha um 0 inicialmente, e depois os numeros depois dele, o C imprime o resultado e reinicializa a pilha. Segue o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#define tamanhoMAX 100

typedef struct{
    int topo;
    int elementos[tamanhoMAX];
}Pilha;

void init(Pilha *p);
int Pilha_vazia(Pilha *p);
int Pilha_cheia(Pilha *p);
int push(Pilha *p,char valor);
char pop(Pilha *p);
void show(Pilha *p);

void init(Pilha *p){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<tamanhoMAX;i++)
        p->elementos[i] = 0;

    p->topo = -1;
}

int Pilha_vazia(Pilha *p){
    return p->topo == -1;
}

int Pilha_cheia(Pilha *p){
    return (p->topo + 1) == tamanhoMAX;
}

int push(Pilha *p,char valor){
    if(Pilha_cheia(p))
        return -1; //aborta a função

    p->topo++;
    p->elementos[p->topo] = valor;
    return 0; //sucesso
}

char pop(Pilha *p){
    char aux;
    if(Pilha_vazia(p) == 1)
        return -1;

    aux = p->elementos[p->topo];
    p->topo--;

    return aux;
}

void show(Pilha *p){
    int i;
    i = p->topo;

    while(i!=-1){
        printf("%d",p->elementos[i]);
        i--;
    }
}

int valor(int c){
   return c-'0';
}

int main(void) {
    int i,j,aux,N;
    Pilha p;
    int x,y,cont=0;
    char op;

    init(&p);

    scanf("%d",&N);
    getchar();

    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        scanf("%c",&op);
        int v = (int)op;

            switch(v)
            {
            case 67: //correspondente a 'C' na tabela ASCII
                show(&p);
                init(&p);
                break;
            case 69: //correspondente a 'E' na tabela ASCII
                push(&p,0);
                break;
            case 43: //correspondente a '+' na tabela ASCII
                y=pop(&p);
                x=pop(&p);
                push(&p,x+y);
                break;
            case 45: //correspondente a '-' na tabela ASCII
                y=pop(&p);
                x=pop(&p);
                push(&p,x-y);
                break;
            case 42: //correspondente a '*' na tabela ASCII
                y=pop(&p);
                x=pop(&p);
                push(&p,x*y);
                break;
            case 47://correspondente a '/' na tabela ASCII
                y=pop(&p);
                x=pop(&p);
                push(&p,x/y);
                break;
            case '^': //o valor 94 aqui não dava certo tbm :/
                y=pop(&p);
                x=pop(&p);
                while(cont != x){
                    aux = aux*y;
                    cont++;
                }
                push(&p,aux);
                break;

            default:
                x=valor(v);
                y=pop(&p);
                push(&p,y*10+x);
                break;
            }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: É necessário que a entrada seja no formato `7{Enter}E10E2-C{Enter}`? Tipicamente, você deveria apertar enter ao invés de digitar E, e não precisaria digitar `C{Enter}` pois a calculadora entende que o símbolo operação significa "calcule o resultado". É um pouco difícil prever o comportamento da calculadora se sair do padrão sem ter outro modelo muito bem definido. Para referência, veja [uma calculadora rpn online](http://icrank.com/data/calculator/calc_app.htm) e o [artigo da Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nota%C3%A7%C3%A3o_polonesa_inversa)

Comment: Infelizmente tem que ser nesse formato :/ Só pra dificultar mais as coisas

Answer (score 1):

Olá!
Pois bem não li seu código por completo então resolvi só passar o olho e ir direto para onde você disse estar o problema. Você disse que ele não está resolvendo potencias, para usar uma variável em uma operação você precisa antes inicializa-la com algum valor, o seu erro é que você está usando a variável `int aux` sem antes inicializa-la.
Como você vai usa-la em operações de multiplicação você precisa inicializa-la com 1, no caso do seu código você deve fazer isso bem antes da iteração do loop `while(cont != x)` onde a variável aux é utilizada e permitir que seja  redefinida com 1 novamente a cada interação do laço `for(i=0;i<N;i++)`.
Assim ficaria:

```
...
for(i=0;i<N;i++){
 ...
 aux = 1; // <--- 
 while(cont != x){
   aux = aux*y;
   cont++;
 }
...
}
```

Agora a resposta não será mais zero.
Ressalto também que você está importando bibliotecas sem necessidade, a `math.h` e `string.h` estão sujando seu código.
Verifiquei também uma redundância no trecho `int v = (int)op`. Você não precisa forçar a conversão para int do caractere gravado em char op pois a própria atribuição faz a conversão do mesmo para o inteiro da tabela ASCII automaticamente.
Ficará assim:

```
int v = op;
```

Quando postar mais perguntas comente mais seu código, assim diminuirá o gasto de tempo para responder. Dê uma pesquisada no uso das bibliotecas. Abraço.

Comment: Muita obrigada pela resposta J. Carvalho, mas infelizmente no meu código ainda está se imprimindo 0. Realmente não entendo o problema dele. De qualquer forma, obrigada pelas dicas da biblioteca e td o mais,abraços!